# UIColorWell does not open

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, storyboard

I have 2 UIViews that I converted to UIColorWells.

```
@IBOutlet weak var colorWell1: UIColorWell!
@IBOutlet weak var ColorWell2: UIColorWell!
```

When I run the app, I see the color wells just fine (see image below). However, when I try to click on them, the actual color picker never opens. It seems like its just the image of the color well showing up.

Is there method I have to create to make them open, or is it built in? This is what I have pertaining to the colorWells below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
colorWell1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(colorWellChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        colorWell2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(colorWellChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
}

 @objc func colorWellChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        colorWell1.backgroundColor = colorWell1.selectedColor
        colorWell2.backgroundColor = team2ColorWell.selectedColor
        
    }
```

This is what the colorWells look like: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6Qzp.png)

This is my folder structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rw8Kq.png)

Comment: `team2ColorWell` is the super view of the colorWell? If yes, what's its type? Is user interaction enabled?

Comment: @Larme User interaction is enabled in both team1ColorWell and team2ColorWell. The type of views for both of these is UIColorWell. Neither colorwells are superviews.

Comment: @Larme i added my folder structure to my post.